# npx react-native run-ios fails

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, simulator

I'm trying to help a new team member to get our RN app working on his Simulator, from CLI or Xcode.

From the CLI, we are getting the following error:

```
Ld /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPFOLDER-bxdehwlqvykiwgbwavwistqbnidi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.app/APP normal x86_64
```

We've tried all the standard solutions such as:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup / pod install
```

Also tried uncommenting the `flipper!()` in Podfile, and tinkering with `Build Phases > Link Binary With Library` in Xcode.

Macbook Pro M2,
OS Monterey,
Xcode 13.4.1

My own computer is an M1, and OS Monterey. I have never had this many problems with trying to start the Simulator.

Any advice will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install Rosetta. However, you mentioned that you also have a m1. Didn't you have to install Rosetta for your application ?

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Solved this issue for me in the past.

Also you could try to create a separated RN app and check if you are having the same issue. ( If you do than the problem is not with rosetta). In this case I would review the steps https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As it turned out, I do have Rosetta installed on my M1's Terminal (I must've forgotten that I installed it, or it came with it?). I'll advise my teammate to check if he has Rosetta.